# Java ssl client identification

Tags: java, ssl

I am using SSL socket server and client programs with mutual identification (ClientAuth). The clients are of two types, each type using its own certificate. How can the server determine the type of a newly connected clent, e.g. the client's certificate alias or some other distinguishable property?

Here is my code that sets up the server and accepts a connection form client:

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

ks.load(new FileInputStream(serverKeystoreFile), serverKeystorePass);
kmf.init(ks, serverCertificatePass);
ks.load(new FileInputStream(serverTruststoreFile), serverTruststorePass);
tmf.init(ks);
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();
SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(port);
sslserversocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);

// accept connection from client
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();

// At this point, I would like to determine the connected client's certificate alias
// or some other property that is unique for each of the acceptable client certificates.
```

Comment: " ... or some other distinguishable property" - In addition to Warren's answer below, you can also call `getCipher` to retrieve the cipher suite. `getCipher` is available on the `SSLContext` and, for example, `HttpsUrlConnection`. I'm not sure its as distinguished as you need, but its definitely a property of the particular connection. You also have the `getSessionContext` which should provide additional session specific information.

Comment: Don't forget to close your input streams when you load your keystores.

Answer (score 3):

After the handshake completes, you should be able to call `SSLSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificate()` on the server to get the client's certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this one was useful for me: `SSLSocket.getSession().getPeerPrincipal().getName()`